# Running Kubernetes locally

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am planning to test Kubernetes locally, but would like to ask some theoretic questions before.

I created a pipeline in python that takes as input a whole bunch of files from a directory, and created a docker image out of it (this is my Pod)

What I understood from the documentation is that the Kubernetes scheduler will choose automatically the minion to deploy for a given task, my question is, using an 8G memory laptop, is there a 'rule' to follow before creating the minion (specifying the number of minions to deploy) based on the amount of memory available in a machine (regardless if it is a laptop or a cluster) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically only ever have one minion/host.  So if you are deploying your minions on physical hardware, there is a 1:1 mapping between minions and physical hosts.

If you are deploying into a virtual cluster on your laptop, you will want to make sure that each virtual minion has enough memory to run at least a single instance of whatever containers you plan on deploying.  "How much is enough?" is a question that only you can answer.